# Why does the numerical integrator return a SystemException[MemoryAllocationFailure]?

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to evaluate numerically an improper integral (over the whole real axis) where the integrand is a product of a standard Gaussian and another  function that is well behaved and that behaves as an exponential as the argument goes to plus or minus infinity. Unfortunately the code gives me some mysterious error SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]. I have plotted the function and it is well behaved. I have also used the Evaluation Monitor to look at the sampling points; they all have decent values, there is no sign of any NaN's. Does anyone have a clue what might be the reason for this odd error and how we fix it? As a matter of fact I know that this integral reads 0.609029  because I have a closed form expression for it that involves error functions and the Owen's T function.

```
{mu, mub, g, sig, T, t, x, 
   x0} = {-1.8585502020861382`, -3.2303167530698937`, 
   2.3548589596045244`, 1.656361404394437`, 0.002429011879560017`, 
   0.00013135816690116285`, 1.5327780661154982`, 0.1447641119376839`} ;
tau = T - t;

phi[x_] := Exp[-x^2/2]/Sqrt[2 Pi];
uu[x_] := (-mub tau + Log[x0/x])/(sig Sqrt[tau]);
JJ0[A_, B_, us_] := 
  1/2 Erf[A/Sqrt[1 + 2 B^2]] + 
   1/\[Pi] (-Sign[A us] Pi/2 + 
      2 \[Pi] OwenT[
        A/Sqrt[1/2 + B^2], (2 A B + us + 2 B^2 us)/(Sqrt[2] A)] + 
      2 \[Pi] OwenT[us, (Sqrt[2] (A + B us))/us]);
Clear[JJ]; 
JJ[A_, B_, 
  us_] := (E^((1 - 4 A B)/(4 B^2)) Erf[A - 1/(2 B) + B us] + 
   E^+us  Erfc[A + B us]);
G[x_, T_] := If[x < x0, -x/2, (x - 2 x0)/2 - x0/2 (
            
      JJ[(-mub Sqrt[T])/(Sqrt[2] sig ), 1/(Sqrt[2] sig Sqrt[T]), 
        Log[x/x0]] + 
       JJ[( mub Sqrt[T])/(Sqrt[2] sig ),  sig/(
         Sqrt[2] 2 mu  Sqrt[T]), ((2 mu )/sig^2) Log[x/x0]] ( (
         sig^2)/(2 mu )) +
       -JJ[(-mub Sqrt[T])/(Sqrt[2] sig ), 1/(Sqrt[2] sig Sqrt[T]), 
         0] - 
       JJ[( mub Sqrt[T])/(Sqrt[2] sig ),  sig/(Sqrt[2] 2 mu  Sqrt[T]),
          0] ( (sig^2)/(2 mu )))];

pl1 = Plot[{G[x Exp[mub tau + sig Sqrt[tau] u], T], phi[u]}, {u, -32, 
    5}, AxesLabel -> {"u", ""}, ImageSize -> 400];
pl2 = Plot[{G[x Exp[mub tau + sig Sqrt[tau] u], T] phi[u]}, {u, -5, 
    5}, AxesLabel -> {"u", "Integrand"}, ImageSize -> 400];
GraphicsGrid[{{pl1, pl2}}]


NIntegrate[
 G[x Exp[mub tau + sig Sqrt[tau] u], T] phi[u], {u, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> 
  Print[{u, G[x Exp[mub tau + sig Sqrt[tau] u], T] phi[u]}]]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: MMA version 13.1 on Windows. Runs without problems. Result= 0.609029

Comment: @Daniel Huber: I have version 11.3 on Windows 64 bit.

Comment: The message would hint that you run out of memory. However I checked,, it needs only between 300 and 400 MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this message split the integration range.

```
NIntegrate[G[x Exp[mub tau + sig Sqrt[tau] u], T] phi[u], {u, -10, 10},AccuracyGoal -> 15, PrecisionGoal -> 10 ] 
(*0.609029*)
NIntegrate[G[x Exp[mub tau + sig Sqrt[tau] u], T] phi[u], {u, -Infinity, -10 },AccuracyGoal -> 15, PrecisionGoal -> 10 ] 
(*1.23726*10^-24*)
NIntegrate[G[x Exp[mub tau + sig Sqrt[tau] u], T] phi[u], {u, 10, Infinity }, AccuracyGoal -> 15, PrecisionGoal -> 10 ] 
(*1.17493*10^-23*)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It did fix the problem indeed. Beforehand , as I was choosing the eight parameters on top of the code snippet, randomly there was always some case when the exception was thrown. Now, this never happens. Good to know that. But what do you think is happening here? I checked in the task manager, we are not allocating too much memory. What might be the reason for this strange error?

Comment: @Przemo Splitting the integration range helps Mathematica's adaptive integration algorithem to handle the case infinite range & vanishing function I think.